# Html encoding in .NET class library

Tags: c#, .net, html-encode

I have a utility class for sending emails. The emails are generated as html.

I'm having problems with encoding special characters which aren't getting displayed correctly.

However, I can't work out how to use `HtmlEncode` as I don't have a current `HttpContext`. Is there a `.Net` class which will translate special characters to html codes without running under `Asp.Net`?

I hope that makes sense, I'm a bit flaky about how all this stuff works. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can import the System.Web namespace and use the HttpUtility class. Altohugh it's a Web assembly I don't think it's neccesary to be running under a Web environment for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I didn't find that!

Comment: Adding a dependency on System.Web is not a great idea for a class library. Use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode() instead.

Answer (score 21):

I believe `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode` will provide this functionality. [MSDN reference for WebUtility.HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388364.aspx)

Comment: +1 for being first but that's .NET 4 only so I can't use unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`HttpUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) class from System.Web.

Answer (score 2):

You should really look into using the `AntiXSS` library of the [WPL](http://wpl.codeplex.com/).

1. You **don't need** System.Web!
2. It uses a white-list inclusion principle (*System.Web encoding uses black-listing*). Only characters that are known to be safe will be trusted and all others will be properly encoded

Answer (score 0):

How about [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx)?